# Python drop columns in string range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I want to drop all columns whose name starts by 'var' and whose content is 'None'.
Sample of my dataframe:

```
id var1 var2 newvar1 var3 var4 newvar2
1  x    y    dt      None f    None
```

Dataframe that I want:

```
id var1 var2 newvar1 var4 newvar2
1  x    y    dt      f    None
```

I want to do this for several files and I do not know how many 'var' I have in all of them. My dataframe has only one row.
Here is the code that I tried:

```
for i in range(1,300):
    df.drop(df.loc[df['var'+str(i)] == 'None' ].index, inplace=True)
```

Error obtained:

```
KeyError: 'var208'
```

I also tried:

```
df.drop(df.loc[df['var'+str(i) for i in range(1,300)] == 'None'].index, inplace=True)
```

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone help me improve my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error occurs because you have no column with that name.
You can use df.columns to get a list of available columns, check if the name `.startswith("var")` and use `df[col].isnull().all()` to check if all values are None.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id", "var1", "var2", "newvar1", "var3", "var4", "newvar2"],
                  data=[[1, "x", "y", "dt", None, "f", None]])


df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("var") and df[col].isnull().all()], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it does not work. Maybe because what I have is "None" not "NaN"

Comment: Is your "None" a string? Or is it None like I defined above?

Comment: If it is a string (because you read it from a file and it maybe didnt get converted), try to replace `df[col].isnull().all()` with `df[col].isin(['None']).all()`

Comment: Great, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```py
out = df.drop(columns=df.filter(regex='^var').isna().all().pipe(lambda s: s.index[s]))
```

```
print(out)

   id var1 var2 newvar1 var4 newvar2
0   1    x    y      dt    f    None
```

Step by step explanation

```
out = df.drop(columns=(df.filter(regex='^var')       # get columns where column header starts with var
                       .isna()                       # is the value none
                       .all()                        # is the whole column none
                       .pipe(lambda s: s.index[s]))  # get the index name where the whole column is none )
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it does not work. Maybe because what I have is "None" not "NaN"

Comment: @MGFern How about doing `df = df.replace('None', None)` before the `drop`?